# Amazon Seller Central - Creating payload hash

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, google-apps-script

I'm trying to send a request to Amazon Selling Partner API.

I reached a point where I now need to include the `marketplaceIds` in the request to get past through this error:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
     "message": "Missing or invalid request parameters: [MarketplaceIds]",
     "code": "InvalidInput"
    }
  ]
}
```

However the hash I'm calculating is not the same that the API suggests:

My Full Canonical Request

```
GET
/orders/v0/orders

host:sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Apps-Script; beanserver; +https://script.google.com; id: UAEmdDd-KyWEWcR137UzUzWb1fu3rUgNviHA)
x-amz-access-token:Atza|IwEBIMBLORaPVaVyqdJnWfDF_zMyAccessToken
x-amz-date:2021-03-17T00:39:12.108Z

host;user-agent;x-amz-access-token;x-amz-date
9a34e897d8be214423d5360dbbab5239cb298102312f94bf7d222f91e4770be9
```

Amazon's Canonical Request

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.

The Canonical String for this request should have been
'GET
/orders/v0/orders

host:sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Apps-Script; beanserver; +https://script.google.com; id: UAEmdDd-KyWEWcR137UzUzWb1fu3rUgNviHA)
x-amz-access-token:Atza|IwEBIMBLORaPVaVyqdJnWfDF_zMyAccessToken
x-amz-date:2021-03-17T00:39:12.108Z

host;user-agent;x-amz-access-token;x-amz-date
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855'
```

The canonical request is composed of the following values ([guide here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-canonical-request.html))

`canonical_request = method + '\n' + canonical_uri + '\n' + canonical_querystring + '\n' + canonical_headers + '\n' + signed_headers + '\n' + payload_hash`

The component I'm missing is the `payload_hash` and it could be because of 2 reasons:

- The content I'm hashing is wrong
- The way I'm hashing is wrong (or both)

**My code:**

I want to get my orders from Amazon API ([guide here](https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/references/orders-api/ordersV0.md#getorder)) and the only mandatory value is `marketplaceIds`:

> A list of MarketplaceId values. Used to select orders that were placed
> in the specified marketplaces.

```
function GetOrders(){
  var access_token = AccessToken();

  //API variables
  var end_point = 'https://sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com';

  //Credential variables
  var aws_region = "eu-west-1";
  var service = "execute-api";
  var termination_string = "aws4_request";

  //CanonicalRequest = httpRequestMethod + '\n' + CanonicalURI + '\n' + CanonicalQueryString + '\n' + CanonicalHeaders + '\n' + SignedHeaders + '\n' + HexEncode(Hash(RequestPayload));
  //CanonicalRequest components:
  var httpRequestMethod = 'GET';
  var canonicalURI = '/orders/v0/orders';
  var canonicalQueryString = '';
  var canonicalheaders = 'host:' + "sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com" + '\n' + 'user-agent:' + 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Apps-Script; beanserver; +https://script.google.com; id: UAEmdDd-KyWEWcR137UzUzWb1fu3rUgNviHA)' + '\n' + 'x-amz-access-token:' + access_token + '\n' + 'x-amz-date:' + isoDate + '\n';
  var signedheaders = 'host;user-agent;x-amz-access-token;x-amz-date';
  
  //Building an object that contains MarketplaceIds array

  var request_parameters =  {
    MarketplaceIds: ["A1PA6795UKMFR9"]
  };
  
  //Hashing the stringify object
  var requestPayloadHashed = digestToHex(JSON.stringify(request_parameters));

  //Building the canonical request
  var canonical_string = httpRequestMethod + '\n' + canonicalURI + '\n' + canonicalQueryString + '\n' + canonicalheaders + '\n' + signedheaders + '\n' + requestPayloadHashed;
  var canonical_signature = Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.SHA_256, canonical_string);
  canonical_request = canonical_signature.map(function(e) {return ("0" + (e < 0 ? e + 256 : e).toString(16)).slice(-2)}).join("");

   //Once the canonical request is completed we continue with the call to the API
   var credential_scope = yearMonthDay + '/' + aws_region + '/' + service + '/' + termination_string;
  var string_to_sign = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256" + '\n' + isoString + '\n' + credential_scope + '\n' + canonical_request;
  var kSecret = ACCESS_KEY;
  var kDate = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(yearMonthDay, "AWS4" + kSecret);
  var kRegion = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(toBytes(aws_region), kDate);
  var kService = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(toBytes(service), kRegion);
  var kSigning = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(toBytes(termination_string), kService);

  var signature = hex(Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(toBytes(string_to_sign), kSigning));
  var options = {
    'method': 'GET',
    'headers': {
      'payload': request_parameters,
      'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Apps-Script; beanserver; +https://script.google.com; id: UAEmdDd-KyWEWcR137UzUzWb1fu3rUgNviHA)',
      'x-amz-access-token': access_token,
      'x-amz-date': isoDate,
      'Authorization': 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=' + ACCESS_ID + '/' + credential_scope + ', SignedHeaders=' + signedheaders + ', Signature=' + signature,
    },
    'muteHttpExceptions': true
  }
  var getOrders = UrlFetchApp.fetch(end_point + canonicalURI + canonicalQueryString, options);
  Logger.log(getOrders);
}
```

I tried to guide myself following this [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html) in Python (the POST call) however I might be missing several things.

Comment: At first, can I confirm that my understanding for your question is correct? 1. When your Google Apps Script is run, the error message showing in the top of your question occurs. Is my understanding correct? 2. When you test [the python script](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html), you confirmed that script worked. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike 1. Correct, when I run this script I get the error that shows at the begining of the post. 2. I use the python script as a reference to update my GAS script only and get the code up to its current state.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I use the python script as a reference to update my GAS script only and get the code up to its current state.`, unfortunately, I cannot understand it. Can I ask you about the detail of it? And, you want to convert ["Using POST (Python)"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html#sig-v4-examples-post) to Google Apps Script. Is that your goal of your this question?